# Postgres: filtering with BETWEEN SYMMETRIC

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to filter out data points based on coordinates using `BETWEEN SYMMETRIC` as in in the following query:

```
SELECT user_id
    , duration
    , distance
    , speed
   FROM trips_metrics
  WHERE lat_start BETWEEN SYMMETRIC (39.45 AND 40.05) AND lat_end  BETWEEN SYMMETRIC (39.45 AND 40.05)
     AND lon_start BETWEEN SYMMETRIC (115.41667 AND 117.5) AND lon_end BETWEEN SYMMETRIC (115.41667 AND 117.5)

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "BETWEEN"
LINE 6: ... BETWEEN SYMMETRIC (39.45 AND 40.05) AND lat_end  BETWEEN SY...
```

To filter user's trip with the geographic area only.

Comment: `BETWEEN SYMMETRIC 39.45 AND 40.05`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use parentheses.  So:

```
lat_start BETWEEN SYMMETRIC 39.45 AND 40.05
```

Of course, your values are already in order, so `SYMMETRIC` is redundant for your query.